# Error in windows application "SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollection[ListType]()"

Tags: c#, winforms, subsonic

I'm running a windows application(x86) platform in a windows server 2012(x64) and I'm using a SubSonic to get data from the SQLserver.

And I got this error from try catch Exception

> at SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollectionListType    at
>   CIS.Server.Automailer.Core.ReportConfig.getReportConfig()    at
>   CIS.Server.Automailer.Automailer.processDownload()    at
>   CIS.Server.Automailer.Program.Main()

Here's my source code:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

    namespace CIS.Server.Automailer
    {
        static class Program
        {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                    Automailer mailer = new Automailer();
                    mailer.processDownload();

                    Application.Run();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log(ex);
                }

            }

            static void Log(Exception ex)
            {
                string stackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
                File.WriteAllText("trace.txt", stackTrace); // path of file where stack trace will be stored.
            }
        }
    }
```

Automailer.cs

```
public void processDownload()
    {
        var data = ReportConfig.getReportConfig();
        var machineCenterIds = data[0].MachineCenterId;
        var reportIds = data[0].ReportId;
        var email = data[0].Email;

        recipient = email;
        string[] splitRepId = reportIds.Split(',');
        int[] repIds = new int[splitRepId.Length];
        int c=0;
        foreach (string repId in splitRepId)
        {
            repIds[c] = Convert.ToInt32(repId);
            c++;
        }
        var reportNames = ReportConfig.getReportName(repIds);
        string[] splitMcIds = machineCenterIds.Split(',');

        int ctr = 0;
        filePaths = new string[splitMcIds.Length * reportNames.Count()];

        ei.processFinished = false;
        foreach (string mcId in splitMcIds)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reportNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                string reportName = Convert.ToString(reportNames[i]);
                string url = Utility.GetTemporaryURL(mcId, reportName);
                string fileName = reportName.Replace(" ", "");// + "_" + j + "_00" + i
                downloadPath = string.Format(configPath, mcId, fileName);
                filePaths[ctr] = downloadPath;
                GenerateMails(url);
                Console.WriteLine(downloadPath);
                ctr++;
            }
        }
        processEmail();
        ei.processFinished = true;
    }
```

ReportConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CIS.Server.Automailer.Core
{
    class ReportConfig
    {
        public static ReportAutomationCollection getReportConfig()
        {      
            return DB.Select().From(ReportAutomation.Schema)
                    .Where(ReportAutomation.Columns.UserId).IsEqualTo("001111d6-cc2a-469a-a1bc-1ccd64e60a08")
                    .ExecuteAsCollection<ReportAutomationCollection>();
        }

        public static ReportTypeCollection getReportName(int[] reportId)
        {
            return DB.Select(ReportType.Columns.ReportName).From(ReportType.Schema)
                                .Where(ReportType.ReportIdColumn).In(reportId.ToString())
                                .ExecuteAsCollection<ReportTypeCollection>();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `getReportConfig()`?

Comment: By the way this application is working in my work station(32 bit pc), this error only occur when I'm trying to run in a windows server 2012(x64).

Comment: Well there isn't a lot of information to go on here, I have a feeling you have a bracket in the wrong place though.... `.UserId).IsEqualTo`

Comment: But I completely debug the program and installed on my workstation and it works fine. The problem is that after i installed the program in the windows server 2012(x64) and try to run, the application is processing in task manager but it will terminate after querying with SubSonic I think.

Comment: Are you using the exact same database with both machines, or do you have a testing and prod db? Also, what's the rest of the exception details?

Comment: Thanks for your comment/hint @Mike Walsh it's nearly to the resolve. That was all the exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a problem with your `database`. since your access now is on the server.

> check your data if both exist on your local and on the Server.

Comment: You got it Dyrandz, I found out that the error is looking for the data which is not present on the server.